# Showing an image based on a dropdown

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a list with a dropdown the has the following

Gold

Silver

Bronze

What i would like it when a user selects say Gold, it shows a image of a gold medal in a column next to it in the same list

Thanks

Comment: This worked awesome. Just needed to add the extension: ="<img src='PATHTOIMAGE/IMAGE_" & [ColorColumn] & ".jpg'>":

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a quick trick, 
A Calculated Column set to Datatype=Number will be interpreted as HTML;
so you can use:

```
="<img src='PATHTOIMAGE/IMAGE_" & [ColorColumn] & "'>"
```

which will display images
IMAGE_Gold
IMAGE_Silver
IMAGE_Bronze

This ofcourse requires images in a document or picture library somewhere.
Don't forget to set the Calculated Column to datatype=Number, or you will see the HTMLcode displayed.

Plus.. it won't work in Display/Edit forms.
To prevent the Calculated Column to show up on those forms hide it.
One quick way is to **NOT** add the Calculated Column to contenttypes (option at the bottom
of the Calculated Column create screeen)

CSR is a cleaner solution but takes JavaScript programming, way more time and you have to add the JSlink to each and every View where you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Client-Side rendering (JS Link)](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/04/14/introduction-to-client-side-rendering-in-sharepoint-2013/) to show the image based on dropdown value.

Please have a look at:

[Client-side rendering (JS Link) code samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)